# how to add or merge two rows in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to pandas , this my data frame

```
name quantity weightage type
AAPL   10      20.0     TECH
FORD   20      12.0     AUTO 
AMZN   15      10.0     TECH
TSLA   20      5.0      AUTO
```

op data frame should be, grouped by tech with sum of quantity and weightage,

```
name  quantity  weightage
TECH   25        30.0
AUTO   40        17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` method to split the data frame according to the values in the `type` column, select `quantity` and `weightage` columns and sum over them:

```py
df.groupby('type')[['quantity', 'weightage']].sum()
```